# How do I properly call a value from a dynamic array? - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call a value from a dynamic array to use later in a VBA function, but I can't call it without throwing an array. What's wrong here?

I've tried changing the array types and calling methods, but errors keep popping up.

```
Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim defaultWidth As Double

defaultWidth = 8.11
lastColumn = 30

'Declare array for column width
Dim widthArray() As Double 
ReDim widthArray(lastColumn)

For c = 1 To lastColumn
    widthArray(c) = defaultWidth
Next c

MsgBox (widthArray(c)) ' error is thrown here
```

It says

> "subscript out of range."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note, you're not actually populating the first element of the array, or `widthArray(0)`. That is, unless you have [`Option Base 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement) specified.

Secondly, if you inspect the value of `c` after the loop terminates, you'll see it is actually `31`. This is because, from the [`For...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) documentation:

> After all statements in the loop have executed, *step* is added to *counter*. At this point, either the statements in the loop execute again (based on the same test that caused the loop to execute initially), or the loop is exited and execution continues with the statement following the `Next` statement.

In this case, `c` is incremented to 31, but the loop terminates. So you'll get a

> Subscript out of range error.

Not sure what you want to do exactly, but you can use [`Ubound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function) perhaps:

```
MsgBox widthArray(Ubound(widthArray)) ' no outer parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this was perfect. Wasn't catching that it would make the value 31. Cheers